# How to create a variable that counts how many other cases has the same ID in SPSS

Tags: variables, count, spss

Trying to solve a puzzle here on SPSS.

I'm trying to find a way to count how many siblings each individual (or case) has, based on a variable named `Mother_ID`. It would basically count how many other cases has the same `Mother_ID` as the current record. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Count within case doesn't work for this problem, as there are way too many different `Mother_ID` in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AGGREGATE` is your best friend here:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/29.0.0?topic=reference-aggregate

```
AGGREGATE 
/BREAK = Mother_ID
 /N_of_siblings = N(Mother_ID).
```

This creates a new variable called N_of_siblings; for each record, it will show how many records there are sharing the same `Mother_ID`

LE:

Following eli-k's comments:
the above code creats a new dataset, containing only `Mother_ID` and the `N_of_siblings` variables. If you want `N_of_siblings` added to your initial dataset, use `/MODE  = ADDVARIABLE`:

```
AGGREGATE 
/MODE  = ADDVARIABLE
/BREAK = Mother_ID
/N_of_siblings = N(Mother_ID).
```

Comment: I think the OP would want `mode=addvariables` ?

Comment: @eli-k: isn't `mode=addvariable` default...?

Comment: Your syntax will create a new dataset with only the break variable and the aggregated one. If we want to add the aggregated variable to be added to the active dataset we need to add `mode=addvariable` - question is what does the OP want?